# TabBar Item Image to Wide

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I use the Users Personal Image as an TabBar Item like this:

```
func setUpProfileImage(){
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

    let ref2 = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID)
     ref2.child("profileImageUrl").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
         if let url = snapshot.value as? String {
             URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, response, error in
                 if error == nil {
                     let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                     

                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     if let lastTabBarButton = self.tabBar.subviews.last, let tabItemImageView = lastTabBarButton.subviews.first {
                         if let accountTabBarItem = self.tabBar.items?.last {
                             accountTabBarItem.selectedImage = nil
                             accountTabBarItem.image = nil
                         }
                         let imgView = UIImageView()
                         imgView.frame = tabItemImageView.frame
                         imgView.layer.cornerRadius = tabItemImageView.frame.height/2
                         imgView.layer.masksToBounds = true
                         imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                         imgView.clipsToBounds = true
                         imgView.image = image
                         self.tabBar.subviews.last?.addSubview(imgView)
                     }
                 }
                }
             }.resume()
         }
     })
}
```

The image gets shown, but it is way to wide - is there a way to make the width the same as the height?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame you set needs to be adjusted, try setting the frame like this:

```swift
let imgView = UIImageView()
let frame = tabItemImageView.frame
imgView.frame = CGRect(
    x: frame.origin.x + (frame.width / 2) - (frame.height / 2),
    y: frame.origin.y,
    width: frame.height,
    height: frame.height
)
```

Comment: Yesss, thank you - it works :) Is there also a way to make the image a tiny bit smaller? I tried adjusting the width and height by /2 or so, but this makes it way to small...

Comment: you could try to subtract only a couple of points from the width and height, like 4? remember that once you change height and width value you will also need yo adjust the origin point values to make the item stay centered!

Comment: Perfect, 16 was the magic number haha - thank you for the quick answer! Enjoy your weekend

Comment: Great to heat that! You too!